# mongodb: Perform operation on data according to date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is a sample JSON object, among 1000 like them, stored in my MongoDB collection.

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b1bb74ffc7ee601c6915939"),
  "groupId": "-abcde",
  "applicationId": "avcvcvc",
  "integration": "web",
  "Category": "message",
  "Action": "message",
  "Type": "newMessage",
  "Id": "activity",
  "data": {
    "test": "good morning"
  },
  "timestamp": 1528543055858.0,
  "createdAt": ISODate("2018-06-09T11:17:35.868+0000"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2018-06-09T11:17:35.868+0000"),
  "__v": NumberInt(0)
}
```

This is a query where i fetch data according to date

```js
db.collection.find({"createdAt" : { $gte : new ISODate("2018-06-09T11:17:35.868+0000") }});
```

This is an operation which i need to perform to the JSON objects recieved from fetching data acc. to date

```js
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $match: { $or: [ { Type:"on mouse hover click" },{Type:"on mouse out"},
                     {Type : "on chat start"},{Type :"Load Event"}
                     ] } },
  { $group: { _id:null , count: { $sum: 1 } } }
] );
```

Is there any way where i can make both these operations perform in a single query rather than fetching data acc. to date first and performing aggregation after? I am new to MongoDB so i cant quite figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just `$match` for the timestamp during aggregation:

```
 db.collection.aggregate( [
   { $match: { "createdAt" : { $gte : new ISODate("2018-06-09T11:17:35.868+0000") }}},
   { $match: { $or: [ { Type:"on mouse hover click" },{Type:"on mouse out"}, {Type : "on chat start"},{Type :"Load Event"} ] } },
   { $group: { _id:null , count: { $sum: 1 } } }
 ]);
```